# How to get token from Web API 2 using external login

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, token

I have got website and WebAPI 2  ( ASP.NET MVC 5 ) hosted at localhost but with different ports.

I try to get **token** using this javascript but no token at all and it redirects to the current website with query string containing username and password.

How to fix it?

```
 <form id="userData">
        <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="UserName" />
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" />
 </form>

var login = function () {

  var loginData= $("#userData").serialize();
  loginData= loginData+ "&grant_type=password";

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:57371/Token',
    data: loginData
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    // Cache the access token in session storage.
    sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
  }).fail(showError);

   return false;
};

$("#login").click(login);

var showError = function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   var responseText = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)
   console.log(responseText.Message + " Code: " + XMLHttpRequest.status);
   $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(responseText, null, 4));
};
```

**Update 1. Cors is enabled OK.**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);
}
private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
                origins: "*",
                headers: "*",
                methods: "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
        }
```

*Update 2. Error*

[image]

Comment: What does the server code look like?

Comment: @Khnle-Kevin It is default ASP.NET WEB API 2 Project it has implemented MS Identity 2.0 and it tested ok. And `EnableCorsAttribute` is enabled properly.

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery is properly loaded and included in your HTML? It looks like the click handler to which you have attached doesn't work at all: `$("#login").click(login);` and the form simply reloads the current page.

Comment: So if you put an `alert` as a first line in the beginning of your `login` function you are seeing this alert being shown when the form is submitted?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Pls take a look at the error.

Comment: @Khnle-Kevin I just added the error message.

Comment: OK, so it seems that your Web API doesn't have CORS enabled properly for the token endpoint and thus you cannot make cross domain AJAX requests to it.

Comment: Could you post your Token Controller method?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, Dimi, CORS error that appears here is often a misleading and not the true root cause

Comment: That's correct, for example if the pre-flight request fails with error 500.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you wait for the DOM to be loaded before subscribing to the `click` event of the login button:

```
$(function() {
    $("#login").click(login);
});
```

Also I would recommend you subscribing to the `submit` event of the form instead of the `click` event of a submit button because a form can be submitted, by for example, the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while the focus is inside some if the textboxes and without clicking on any button and thus missing your AJAX call:

```
$(function() {
    $('#userData').submit(login);
});
```

This will guarantee that no matter how this form was submitted your AJAX call will execute instead of simply reloading the current page and appending the username and password as query string parameters to it (which is the behavior that you are observing at the moment).

---

UPDATE:

It looks like your Web API simply doesn't allow CORS and thus the request is blocked.

You may have a look at the [`following article`](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for enabling CORS in Web API.

Answer (score 1):

Change type

```
    input type="submit"
```

to

```
    input type="button"
```

Reason: "submit" submits the entire form so it conflicts to the desired behavior. Whereas "button" defines a clickable button (mostly used with a JavaScript to activate a script) as described in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp.

HTH